# cannot run web pack and cannot run project

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, react-tsx

When I run the web pack command

```
.\node_modules\.bin\webpack -w
```

in my project, I get the following error
[image]

and when I

```
dotnet run
```

I get the following error
[image]

I have the exact same project as my teammates but it just does not want to work on my laptop. How can I fix this and run the project?

Comment: Updating nodejs version?

Comment: Indeed, try updating node version. The arrow function `=>` is not recognized.

Comment: Nice folder name though. Godverdomme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex and Chris R have pointed out in their comment the solution was to update my nodeJS